Dynamically display column in B page based on the display_type in A page in oracle apex 23.1.1
In Oracle Apex. There are two pages A and B
In A we will create datapoints which becomes a column in page B to achieve this we have created page items for all the columns of page B and synced it with actual columns of B.
Now I got struck  In A page There is a column Display_Type and when user created a new datapoint and selected the Display_Type of that datapoint as LOV the column in page B must be display as LOV
So any solution to achieve this without creating a new function and only using PL/SQL.
I have created a new hidden page item and give a dynamic action to it to display the column based on the display_type but it did not workout.

I have no idea what any of that that means. Please show it with a minimal reproducible example.

So if the end user creates a datapoint in PAGE A and want the datapoint to be displayed as List of Values in Page B the column has to behave as List of values automatically when he wants it to be as List of values... How to do it
